# How do I do error hanlding in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets do a simple example. Let's say I want to check if the user is logged in, see if he has permission to see a conversation then get the messages of the conversation. Is there any way to do this in SQL with one query? Here is some pseudo code

```
@uid = select userid from sessions where session=@session
if @uid == empty Error NotLoggedIn
@IsUser = select 1 from conversation_users where conversation_id=@convo_id AND userid=@uid
if @IsUser == false Error NotAllowed
-- Actual query here
select body, time, user from conversation where conversation_id=@convo_id
```

Comment: if you want to `select body, time, user` after logic, you need a function. If you need to just perform logic, `DO` single statement would work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot throw errors/exceptions in pure SQL, it is not designed to allow that. (Apart from the obvious ones, like *division by zero* from i.e. `select 0/0`. You *could* (ab)use the `CASE` expression to make it conditional, i.e. `select case when false then 0/0 end` will never throw the error.)

The usual SQL equivalent for what you want is to run separate queries & build your logic at your (SQL-)client side. Also, when the error reasons do not matter that much, you can use less queries, i.e.:

```
select c.body, c.time, c.user
from   conversation c
join   conversation_users using (conversation_id)
join   sessions using (userid)
where  session         = :session
and    conversation_id = :convo_id
```

This just won't return a row in case of your errors. It is also possible, to return all data at once, to determine the error cause on your (SQL-)client side:

```
with logged_in as (
  select userid, :convo_id conversation_id
  from   sessions
  where  session = :session
),
user_allowed as (
  select count(1) > 0 is_allowed
  from   logged_in
  join   conversation_users using (userid, conversation_id)
)
select    l.userid is not null is_logged_in,
          a.is_allowed,
          c.body,
          c.time,
          c.user
from      user_allowed a
left join logged_in l on true
left join conversation using (conversation_id)
```

If you **really** need PostgreSQL to throw custom error though, you'll need to use [`plpgsql`'s `RAISE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html).